# Best way to optimize for discrete input variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to define a function that looks for two parameters, say A and B, such that their product is equal or greater than a given value, with the condition that A and B are multiple of 5. Aditionally, I'd like that ratio A/B is equal or greater than a given input ratio.

Here's what I have so far:

Objective function: `product(x)`
Constraints: `product(x) => required_product; A % 5 = 0; B % 5 = 0; A / B => input_ratio`

```
def pair_designer(required_product, input_ratio):
x0 = np.asarray([5, 5])
cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0] % 5},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1] % 5},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: product(x) - required_product},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: (np.max(x) / np.min(x)) - input_ratio},
        ]
v = minimize(product, x0=x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, options={'ftol': 1e-10})
return v.x

def product(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]

print(pair_designer(1000, 2))
```

Code works for first constraint, but completely fails when adding second and third constraints. Can you help me resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: scipy.minimize is about continuous optimization. You will need discrete- or mixed-optimization procedures. E.g. MIP or MINLP solvers (not available within scipy).

Comment: Do you know if there are any MINLP algorithm available in Python or R?